# Why does my graphs in matplotlib draw ontop of previous graphs in the same image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating graphs in matplotlib following a python  tutorial and I have my graphs saved as '.png' in the default folder from the Spyder IDE and it seems to create a weird problem where when I create a graph that's saved as a '.png' if I create another graph that's also saved as a '.png' afterwards the imagery from my previous picture(s) also appears in the next one and so on which is not the case in the tutorial i'm following. As you can see in the pictures one has the pink markers in both images even though it's only supposed to appear in one image as well as lines from previous graphs.

[image: Code for figure 52 graph]

[image: Code for figure 51 graph]

[image: figure 51]

[image: figure 52]

Here is the tutorials I followed

https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_matplotlib_marker_color_hotpink
https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_matplotlib_line_dotted

The parts of the code that say `plt.show()` in the tutorial were omitted from my code in favor of `plt.savefig()` because `plt.show()` created an executable that took a long time to load on my computer and needed `matplotlib.use('TkAgg)` to work while `plt.savefig()` instantly saves your graphs as a '.png'.  The `plt.savefig(stdout,buffer) sys.stdout.flush()` bit of code wouldn't work for me at all so I omitted it, it presented me with this error "AttributeError: 'TTYOutStream' object has no attribute 'buffer' "

Comment: Why are you editing and running the same file if you want different plots?

Comment: I have downvoted because the question is unclear, hasn't followed the guideline suggested above and is not [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @OneCricketeer I have many different graphs to code from the tutorials (the screenshots show figure 51 and 52) and running them all in the same file was just an arbitrary choice but no worries I found a solution to the problem

Comment: Didn't know I wasn't supposed to post pictures thanks for letting me know

Comment: In my experience, I always use different figure names

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in case anyone else comes across this strange problem in the future.

```
import sys
import matplotlib
import tkinter
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
```

Import tkinter and 'TkAgg) so you can use the tkinter GUI library for defining the look and feel of the graphs before writing the rest of your code . For whatever reason, i'm not sure why this stops graphs drawing over one another if you choose to create and edit them in the same file.